# No display unless recovery mode on boot. Software mode aftwerwards using intel integrated 10900/Z590

Tags: boot, drivers, intel-graphics, integrated

First time user of linux in general so my knowledge is EXTREMELY limited. I recently installed Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.1 on my Intel 10900/Asus Z590 server rig. The problem I am encountering is that a few seconds after choosing the linux bootloader, the screen goes black and doesn't recover. I have to reboot and choose recovery mode in order to get any video.

After booting, I get a messages from the driver manager that I am running in software mode and that I should update my drivers. I of course do so, but it tells me that everything is installed to the latest ones. I am including a few informational command dumps just to see if anyone can point me in the right direction to try and solve this. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated to get me on my way:

```
sudo lspci -vk | grep -A 15 VGA

DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8694
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel modules: i915

sudo lsmod | grep i9
i915                 1990656  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
drm                   491520  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
video                  49152  2 asus_wmi,i915

glxinfo | grep Mesa
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-42b3513 2021-06-14 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-42b3513 2021-06-14 focal-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.0-devel (git-42b3513 2021-06-14 focal-oibaf-ppa)

inxi
CPU: 10-Core Intel Core i9-10900 (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 4700/800/5200 MHz Kernel: 5.4.0-74-generic x86_64 Up: 3d 22h 42m 
Mem: 7850.3/64123.1 MiB (12.2%) Storage: 96.86 TiB (97.4% used) Procs: 396 Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38 

dpkg --list | grep intel
ii  intel-media-va-driver:amd64                20.1.1+dfsg1-1                        amd64        VAAPI driver for the Intel GEN8+ Graphics family
ii  intel-microcode                            3.20210608.0ubuntu0.20.04.1           amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs
ii  libdrm-intel1:amd64                        2.4.106+git2106100500.d61543~oibaf~f  amd64        Userspace interface to intel-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20200226-1              amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver

    cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic root=UUID=3a0eeeee-a675-43ae-aea6-6a6477285672 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
```

Comment: Sorry, but we don't support Mint here... only standard Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey TibuJenkins! I suggest you to ask this question in [unix.se]. Please go through this [help/on-topic] article.